# Get record position in SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

I have a rank system on my Discord bot, and I am trying to display a message like ('You are rank #5') So I need to query my database, but I am not that great with SQL (I use better-sqlite3)
What I have tried is evidently wrong. Can someone help me, please?
My attempt:

```js
    const userRank = db.prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM scores WHERE points <= 113 AND guild = ? ORDER BY points DESC').all(message.guild.id);
    console.log(userRank);
```

I would like the console.log to output '5' in this case but the current output says '1' (check photo for database records)

[image: databse]

Comment: Would it make more sense to use a `>=` to see how many more records have more points or matching points? If you dont care about ties, then `>` should work. You are on the right track already it seems.

Comment: Yes, I made that mistake, see my answer to see how stupid I was.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to say 5, you should remove guild from WHERE clause and flip comparison operator.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM scores WHERE points >= 113 ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just an idiot, my code was almost right, change `<=` to `>=` and it was working fine, however, when looking at my database, I had not filtered it by guild. So it was giving the correct answer, I was just looking at the wrong table.
answer:

```js
    const userRank = db.prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM scores WHERE points >= 64 AND guild = ? ORDER BY points DESC').all(message.guild.id);
```